# Resize an image in windows phone with out losing its quality

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

How I can resize an image in windows phone without losing its quality. I tried the below given method but the quality of the image fades in a fair margin. Can anyone update a better method for resizing my image.

```
            btmMap = new WriteableBitmap(biInput);
            var source = WriteableBitmapContextExtensions.GetBitmapContext(btmMap);
            btmMap = WriteableBitmapExtensions.Resize(btmMap, (int)imgWidth, (int)imgHeight,     WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.Bilinear);
```

I also tried this method but the result is same :

```
                var wbOutput = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(biInput, (int)imgWidth, (int)imgHeight);
                wbOutput.SaveJpeg(ms, wbOutput.PixelWidth, wbOutput.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                bmp.SetSource(ms);
                ms.FlushAsync();
```

Comment: Image get pixelated while resizing.

Comment: What do you mean by resizing ? If you want to increase the size of the image of course it will result in a loss of quality. In the same way you will observe that you quality decrease if you compress your image into a Jpeg format.

Answer (score 2):

Download, reference and use [6.5 KB DLL from here](http://bicubic.codeplex.com/) for bicubic resizing. It produces better result than bilinear method in WriteableBitmapExtensions.

P.S. Excellent question! I've just updated my app to use better resizing method for generating images for my live tile.

Comment: I tried this method, but it didn't make any huge change in my application.

Comment: It means the resizing was not the main reason why you've observed the quality degradation of your image..